# organize/group an array based on condition - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I simplify an array

`[ china, country1(city1), country1(city2), country1(city3)), korea, australia]` to

```
[ china, country1(city1, city2, city3), korea, australia]
```

Comment: Change `country1` to accept multiple arguments? Of course that will also change the number of elements in the array.

Comment: The number of elements in country1 could differ. How can I change country1 to accept arguments ? I thought it is just an array element.

Comment: `country1` appears to be a function. Is that not the case? Your question is not clear at all. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array elements

1. Extract the country and city separately
2. Update the country-city map(your object that keeps track of countries mapped to which cities)
3. Go through the keys of this object and create a new array with your country-city. If that country has a city array, use `join(',')` to get a comma-separated string of your cities.

```js
var cityRegex = /\((.*)\)/;
var countryRegex = /([^()]*)\(?.*\)?/;

var countryCityArray = ['china', 'country1(city1)', 'country1(city2)', 'country1(city3)', 'korea', 'australia'];

var countryCityMap = {};

countryCityArray.forEach(function(countryCity) {
  var matches = countryRegex.exec(countryCity);
  var country = matches[1]
  if (!countryCityMap[country]) {
    countryCityMap[country] = [];
  }

  matches = cityRegex.exec(countryCity);

  if (matches && matches.length) {
    var city = matches[1];
    countryCityMap[country].push(city);
  }

});

var targetArray = Object.keys(countryCityMap).map(function(country) {
  var countryCity = country;
  if (countryCityMap[country].length) {
    countryCity = countryCity + '(' + countryCityMap[country].join(',') + ')';
  }
  return countryCity;
});

console.log(targetArray);
```

Comment: I tried it. The solution does not work if the array element has other special character like : var array = ['abc', 'xyz( test2 )', 'x&z( test3 )', 'x&z( test4 )', 'pqr','kl-m'];

Comment: @SAM, the regex had to be modified. See my updated answer